# How to get contact link on nav bar to change to an envelope icon on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to make the contact link in my nav bar change to an envelope icon on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways to do it. One is to have two containers within your button, one with the word contact the other with the envelope. Hide the envelope one with `display: none;` and toggle them on hover of the button like this..

```
.contact-button-word {
    display: block;
}
.contact-button-icon {
    display: none;
}
.contact-button:hover .contact-button-word {
    display: none;
}
.contact-button:hover .contact-button-icon {
    display: block;
}
.contact-button-icon img {
    /* your imgage/icon styling */
    /* assuming you're using an image, you may be using something like font awesome */
}

<ul>
    <li class="original-class contact-button">
        <a href=""> 
            <span class="contact-button-word">contact</span>
            <span class="contact-button-icon"><img src="icon.png"></span>
        </a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

*original-class - you may already have a class assigned to your li. If so you can add multiple classes to a tag with css, just leave a space between them. original class is just meant to demonstrate the class you already have there, if any.

Comment: So in order to do this I will need to go into my <li> and add the button tag inside of it? Sorry if this seems like a dumb question I am fairly new to programming and in order to learn I decided to build a website for a friend.

Comment: @DeAndre I changed the code to give you a better idea of what I mean based on what I assume to be your layout.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm new to this forum so I don't know how to share the code I have with you.

Comment: @DeAndre I recommend an account with [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/) Both are great ways to practice and share code. You can also edit your answer to post your code. Try to strip out all the unnecessary stuff for brevity.

Comment: @DeAndre Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/umg1cojr/) to demonstrate jsfiddle and the hover toggle.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use font-awesome cdn to ahow the envelope icon. just add this cdn stylesheet in your `<head>` tag.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href=""https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

See this example:

```css
a{
 text-align:center;  
  width:150px;
}
a .changeIconLink {
    display: block;
}
a .changeIconIcon {
    display: none;
}
a.changeIcon:hover .changeIconLink {
    display: none;
}
a.changeIcon:hover .changeIconIcon {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <li>
    <a class="changeIcon">
        <span class="changeIconLink">contact</span>
        <span class="changeIconIcon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
    </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!